# What if eth0 not configured on Azure VM

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

I have 3 NICs deployed on a Azure VM say eth0, eth1 and eth2. But I configure only eth1 and eth2 not eth0. My network configuration marked as failed. 
Is it necessary to configure eth0 on Azure VM? If yes, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's necessary to configure **the primary network interface** as the primary NIC is used for communicating with resources over a network connection. **Since the primary interface on an Azure Linux virtual machine (VM) is eth0.** If eth0 isn't configured, the VM is not accessible over a network connection even when other tools indicate the VM is up.

When you set multiple NICs in Azure VM. One of the NICs on a multi-NIC VM needs to be primary.

> Azure assigns a default gateway to **the first (primary) network
>   interface** attached to the virtual machine. Azure does not assign a
>   default gateway to additional (secondary) network interfaces attached
>   to a virtual machine. Therefore, you are unable to communicate with
>   resources outside the subnet that a secondary network interface is in,
>   by default.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/multiple-nics#configure-guest-os-for-multiple-nics